# Testcontainers do not start after replacing Docker Desktop with minikube

Tags: docker, minikube, docker-desktop, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I want to make my testcontainers in Java integration tests work with minikube replacing Docker Desktop.

I followed below article to get started:
https://www.atomicjar.com/2021/10/docker-on-windows-and-macos/#minikube

This is what I've got in testcontainers.properties

```
docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy
docker.host=tcp\://192.168.64.2\:2376
docker.cert.path=/Users/username/.minikube/certs
docker.tls.verify=true
```

Although my docker is up and running, I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

Can anybody please suggest anything to make it working?

TA

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle try -no-daemon flag to use a new daemon. Your old gradle daemon still using your previous testcontainers properties, also restart your IDE if you're running your build inside.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Minikube and Intellij editor, and updating testcontainer-bom to be the latest - from 1.15 to 1.16.2, I was able to pull some third-party docker images. This means docker is working now.

However, I'm still trying to find a way to work with local images (Other application docker images) for integration testing as it used to work with Docker Desktop.